Solscan token list
I wan to ask how to get info of all custom tokens in Solscan.
I know that i can get list of ALL tokenes:
url = "https://pro-api.solscan.io/v1.0/token/list?sortBy=market_cap&direction=desc&limit=10"    

headers = {"token":"token"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)

But I want to get info only about my custom tokens whose address is in array TOKENS_LIST_ARRAY = ["asdasd", "aweq2"...]
